# How to find all dual optimal solutions?

Tags: self-learning, linear-programming

A dictionary from a standard form LP problem is given and asked to find all optimal dual solutions:

$x_4 = 5 - x_1 - 2x_2$

$x_5 = 0 - x_1 - x_2 + x_3$

$x_6 = 20 - 7x_1 - 3x_2 + 5x_3$

____________________.

$z = -3x_1 - x_2 - x_3$

I think only using complementary slackness is not sufficient for this problem because by that I can only find one solution but not all, can someone help me with this problem?

(I made a post on this but didn't receive any response so I decided to make another one)

Comment: Please don't self-delete and re-post.  If you wish to draw attention to a particular question, there's a bounty system on the SE network.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 thanks, i wasn't aware of that. I'll follow that next time.

Comment: @PiCubed If you haven´t evaluated the primal solution you cannot find the dual solution by applying the complementary slackness theorem. Another approach is to transform the primal problem into the dual problem and then solve the corresponding dual problem. In both cases, you have to solve a problem first.

Comment: @callculus thanks, but isn't the above equation already a solution? since all coefficient of basic variable in z are negative

Comment: @PiCubed At the first view I thought the slack variables are the basic variables. What do you think the solution is?

Comment: @callculus sorry i meant non basic variables $x_1, x_2, x_3$, i think the solution for the above (primal) is $(0,0,0,5,0,20)$. I could use complementary slackness to find the corresponding dual solution, but the question is how do i find "all" the dual optimal solutions

Comment: @PiCubed I doubt that this is the optimal solution since $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are at the objective function only. For your interpretation of the primal solution we get $z=0$. Maybe this is one of the optimal solution, but I´m not sure. I´m not really able to understand what primal problem we have here due the form it is written here.

Comment: the z here is the function we are trying to maximize. and x4, x5, x6 are the slack variable of the initial constraint $x1+x2-x3 \leq 5$, $x1+x2-x3 \leq 0$, $7x1+3x2-5x3 \leq 20$. the z here just happens to be the optimal solution because all coefficients of the non basic variables are negative (? I'm not sure if that is the way to see this problem

Comment: @PiCubed I think you´re right with your constraints. They can be insert  into the (initial) tableau. Usually the coefficient of the obj. function are negative if the obj. function has to be maximized. $s_1,s_2,s_3$ denotes the slack variables here. The following table show how I think the table should looks like.

Comment: @PiCubed $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}  \hline &x_1 &x_2& x_3&s_1&s_2&s_3&\text{RHS} \\ \hline  s_1 &1&2&0&1&0&0&5 \\ \hline s_2&1&1&-1&0&1&0&0 \\ \hline s_3 &7&3&-5&0&0&1&20 \\ \hline -z &-3&-1&-1&0&0&0&0 \\ \hline \end{array}$$